# How do you add types to an import of package.json?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to import package.json into a project, but it's not typed the way I want.
For example, `'description' in packageJson && <meta name='description' content={packageJson.description}/>` will throw a type error if description is not in the package.json file.
I know that type-fest has a PackageJson type, but how do you use it with import?

Comment: Can you show an example of what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: `'description' in packageJson && <meta name='description' content={packageJson.description}/>` does not throw an error if description is not in the package.json file. Do you mean that it will have a *compile* time error? If so, please include the error and the type of packageJson.

Comment: The json type imported will only be the same type as whatever properties are already there. A property like description is optional, so if its not there, it will throw a type error. This would be the same as `const a = {}; 'b' in a && a.b` which does throw a type error. My goal is only to type the imported package.json file so that it won't throw a type error, or some other workaround

Comment: An example of how I'm using it is if I have a description in the packageJson, I would use that as the description for a website with the meta tag, but if it doesn't exist, there's no meta tag. Currently tho, it will throw a type error